# Run make with Makefile in memory

Tags: makefile

Suppose I have an encrypted Makefile on hand, I want to write a Perl program to decrypt it and run `make -f` with it. Is this possible without writing the decrypted Makefile back to harddisk?

Comment: Can I ask it what context are you using an encrypted makefile?

Comment: Yes, I know it's rare. It's just a thought.

Comment: Can you show us the makefile so we can give you a better answer :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have your program write the decrypted Makefile to stdout and pipe it to make -.

See man make, the part that says:

> If makefile is `-', the standard input is read.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting [LD_PRELOAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ldpreload-trick) when you run `make` to give `make` some fake fopen/fclose functions that read the makefile out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
make -f <(decrypt file)
```

This will work on linux and some other systems. It does not rely on make supporting this functionality. It is done in the OS. See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution

P.S. you will want to consider swap space, telling make not to swap.

Also this will not help with files included by the first.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an encrypted file system. A shell script could launch a key agent, for the file system then the make can run retrieving and saving everything to/from the encrypted file system. I have done successfully done this with sshfs (not an encrypted file system, but an encrypted connection to a remote file system locked in a room).